# How do I deploy a Java ME app to Bada?

Tags: java-me, bada

I've read that it's possible to develop and deploy Java ME apps to Samsung Bada phones. But how do you deploy the apps to the emulator and/or phone? Are there any Eclipse plugins for this?

Any pointers or links to a guide would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

copy the .jar file to the phone, then open it inside the phone's filesystem, it will ask you to install the java-app, then you can use it. to test your java-app in an emulator, i would suggest you use netbeans to write the java-app, it includes a jme-app-emulator